# Fill all related tables in a typed dataset by parent id of the parent table

Tags: c#, asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset

Consider the scenario.. if i have a parent table having several child tables and each child table have several child tables and these grand child tables have several more child tables and so on ...

Like ..

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <grandChild>
      <furtherGrandChild>and so on </furtherGrandChild>
    </grandchild>
  </child>

  <child>
    <grandChild>
      <furtherGrandChild>and so on </furtherGrandChild>
    </grandchild>
  </child>
  <child>
    <grandChild>
      <furtherGrandChild>and so on </furtherGrandChild>
    </grandchild>
  </child>
</parent>
```

so after looking at the scenario at first i thought that using typed datasets would make my life easier, as i won 't be needing to write Object classes and rest of the SQL, which would have been a hell load of repetitive work. But now i am stuck ,

i just dont know that how to fill the dataset based on the ID of my parent table at once ? or i have to do it one by one :( (That's not fair) .. i have more than 200 tables normalized in the way i described above ... any possible solution to this ? either bby using typed datasets or using linq to sql or whatever ... i just need all the data in exactly the same schema in the dataset at the end, because then i have to generate the xml from this data ...

and offcourse i am not going to fill dataset with all the data first and then traverse it ...

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question. It also depends on what indexes you have available, and how your tables are related to each other, which isn't clear. Do you mean you have 200 levels of nested parent/child/grandchild/greatgrandchild . . . down to great*200 ? This sounds like an unusual design.

Comment: ask anything, which isn 't clear sir,there aren't 200 levels, but yes there are levels what you can phrase like parent/child/grandchild/so on ....